# How set paper trail whodunnit for workers using sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, paper-trail-gem

I am trying to implement that when inside a worker a model that has paper trail is updated the whodunnit must be set with 'worker', I tried many things without success, the last one was to try a solution found in a [github thread](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/issues/524#issuecomment-260335058) the problem is that I have workers with perfom without / with 1 or multiple params( I changed this to set PaperTrail.request.whodunnit = 'worker')

How can I set whodunnit before or around each perform, so that the whodunnit in the versions is saved as whodunnit: worker?

my workers look like this:

```
module ModuleName
  module Workers
    class WorkerClass
      include Sidekiq::Worker

      sidekiq_options queue: 'default', retry: true


      def perform # here with none, 1 or more params
        # update some model
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for me

base_worker.rb

```
class BaseWorker
  extend ActiveModel::Callbacks
  define_model_callbacks :perform

  around_perform :set_paper_trail_whodunnit

  def set_paper_trail_whodunnit
    PaperTrail.request.whodunnit = "worker-#{self.class.name}"
    yield
    PaperTrail.request.whodunnit = nil
  end

  def perform(*args)
    run_callbacks(:perform) do
      perform!(*args)
    end
  end

  def perform!(*_args)
    raise 'Missing your #perform! method implementation'
  end
end
```

workers:

```
module ModuleName
  module Workers
    class WorkerClass < ::BaseWorker
      include Sidekiq::Worker

      sidekiq_options queue: 'default', retry: true


      def perform! # here with none, 1 or more params
        # update some model
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You might want to put the `whodunnit = nil` in an `ensure`, in case there's an exception.